# reference a string that already has double quotation mark

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with Excel VBA where it's saying run-time error '1004'.

Here's the code:

```
Sub modifyformula()

Dim formla As String

formla = Cells(21, 48).Formula

Cells(21, 48).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(" & formla & ",," & formla & ")"

End Sub
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is if the tell the VBA to add in "=IF(ISERROR(" ... to an existing formula, and I will tell VBA to update every cell that contains a similar formula.

The formula in the cell is: =GETPIVOTDATA($AU$6&$AU$19,Pivottable!$A$3,"mis_month",AV$3,"channel2",$AU21)

I think the problem is the double quotation mark in the actual formula is causing the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance to those who can help me :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut out the "=" from the formula before concatenating it:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const NEW_FORM As String = "=IF(ISERROR(<f>),,<f>)"

    Dim f As String, c As Range

    Set c = Cells(21, 48)

    If c.HasFormula Then
        f = Right(c.Formula, Len(c.Formula) - 1)
        c.Formula = Replace(NEW_FORM, "<f>", f)
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: `IFERROR()` is a bit easier to use here, depending on what versions of excel you need to support.